# Distributing shared objects with my program

Tags: c++, linker, ld

I've figured out which `.so` files are needed by my program to work on other machines, but I'm not sure what I need to do with them to make sure that my program will find them and link with them on execution.

I know that on Windows platforms I can just dump the `.dll` files in the directory of the executable and be done with it. This doesn't seem to be the case on Linux, though.

```
$ ls
libjrtp.so.3.9.1  libjthread.so.1.3.1  libQtCore.so.4  libQtGui.so.4  streamer
$ ./streamer 
./streamer: error while loading shared libraries: libjrtp.so.3.9.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I find it odd that the program can't link with the library even though it's basically sitting right there in the working directory. Why isn't it linking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not linking because `.` isn't in the `RPATH` of your binary (You can use `-R` to set this). Unix systems don't look in the current directory for needed files like Windows does/used to do. You can confirm this with `ldd ./binary`.

Comment: I work with `qmake`, so I added `QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Xlinker -R .` to my PRO file, which did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @Pieter I should have mentioned that this isn't always a good idea because it will look for any of its shared objects in `.` which gives unprivileged users a possible chance to interpose their own shared libraries in place of legitimate ones. At least think one more moment about packaging your shared library into a more commonly used directory.

Comment: Just to be clear on this... will the binary look in the *working* directory or in its *own* directory? I only see a possible security risk in the first case. The second solution would be safer, but I don't know if it's possible to achieve.